# Remotely performing actions on another computer via batch file

Tags: batch-file, remote-access

I have these statements in a batch file, which need to be modified to execute on another computer on the network:

```
oradim -new -sid %ORACLE_SID% -intpwd %pass% -startmode M
D:
cd D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\database
echo control_files = (d:\oracle\databases\%ORACLE_SID%\control01.ora, d:\oracle\databases\%ORACLE_SID%\control02.ora, d:\oracle\databases\%oracle_SID%\control03.ora) > init%ORACLE_SID%.ora
echo undo_management = auto >> init%ORACLE_SID%.ora
echo db_name = %ORACLE_SID% >> init%ORACLE_SID%.ora
echo db_block_size = 8192 >> init%ORACLE_SID%.ora
```

I have previously used:

```
net use \\%ip% %pass%/USER:%user%
sc \\%ip% stop %serviceName%
```

...to stop services on another computer. But I am not sure how that knowledge can be applied in this case.

Assistance would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) tool from the [PsTools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) collection to remotely run any command on a remote computer that you have access to.

You would use it like below to run commands from a specific batch file name `fileName`.

```
psexec \\%ip% -u %user% -p %pass% fileName
```